# How do I hide <li> when the <span> inside contains certain text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to hide all the  which contains text "__" inside  in the following code

```
<ul class="bc-product__spec-list">
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Weight:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">0.5 kg</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Width:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">25 cm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Depth:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8 cm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Height:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8.5 cm</span>
    </li>

    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Series:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Boxco S Series</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Enclosure - Base Colour:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Grey</span>
    </li>

    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__length:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">80mm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__width:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">250mm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__height:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">85mm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing unit:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">carton</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing qty:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">32</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__related_product_json:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">/content/related_json/related-BC-CGS-082508-K-en.json</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Unit of Measure:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">item</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've tried

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".bc-product__spec-title > span:contains('__')").parent().hide();
  });
</script>
```

but it doesn't work. And I'm inserting the code via Google Tag Manager for a Wordpress site, not sure if that's why the code is not working? Please help.

Here's a Stack Snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bc-product__spec-title > span:contains('__')").parent().hide();
});
```

```html
<ul class="bc-product__spec-list">
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Weight:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">0.5 kg</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Width:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">25 cm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Depth:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8 cm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Height:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8.5 cm</span>
  </li>

  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Series:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Boxco S Series</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Enclosure - Base Colour:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Grey</span>
  </li>

  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__length:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">80mm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__width:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">250mm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__height:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">85mm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing unit:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">carton</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing qty:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">32</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__related_product_json:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">/content/related_json/related-BC-CGS-082508-K-en.json</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Unit of Measure:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">item</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 window.onload = function () {
    //firstly we select all li elements with the class "bc-product__spec"
    var allListItems = document.getElementsByClassName("bc-product__spec");

    for (var i = 0; i < allListItems.length; i++) {
      //we get the span in the current li item
      var item = allListItems.item(i).firstElementChild;
      if (item.innerHTML == "__") {
        //we final set the display style property of the li to none if its span contains a certain word "__" in my case
        allListItems.item(i).style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  };
```

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but it hides all the <li>, anything that might went wrong?

Comment: in this line:  if (item.innerHTML == "__")   replace "__" by the text you are looking for  i just edited the code its  ==   not   !=

Comment: Changed it to "item.innerHTML.includes('__')" and it works!. Thank you

Comment: great happy i could help

Answer (score 1):

`.bc-product__spec-title` identifies the span that has the content, not its parent. So you don't want the child selector, use `:contains` on that element itself. I'd then use `.closest("li")` to select the `li`, just in case the HTML changes slightly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bc-product__spec-title:contains('__')").closest("li").hide();
});
```

Live copy:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".bc-product__spec-title:contains('__')").closest("li").hide();
});
```

```html
<ul class="bc-product__spec-list">
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Weight:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">0.5 kg</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Width:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">25 cm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Depth:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8 cm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Height:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8.5 cm</span>
  </li>

  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Series:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Boxco S Series</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Enclosure - Base Colour:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Grey</span>
  </li>

  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__length:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">80mm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__width:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">250mm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__height:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">85mm</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing unit:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">carton</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing qty:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">32</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__related_product_json:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">/content/related_json/related-BC-CGS-082508-K-en.json</span>
  </li>
  <li class="bc-product__spec">
    <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Unit of Measure:</span>
    <span class="bc-product__spec-value">item</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Looped approach** - Checking the list of items and then determining whether they contain the value specified.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const product = $(".bc-product__spec-title");

    $(product).each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf("__") >= 0) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    const product = $(".bc-product__spec-title");

    $(product).each(function (index) {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf("__") >= 0) {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="bc-product__spec-list">
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Weight:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">0.5 kg</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Width:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">25 cm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Depth:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8 cm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Height:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">8.5 cm</span>
    </li>

    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Series:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Boxco S Series</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Enclosure - Base Colour:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">Grey</span>
    </li>

    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__length:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">80mm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__width:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">250mm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__height:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">85mm</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing unit:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">carton</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__packing qty:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">32</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">__related_product_json:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">/content/related_json/related-BC-CGS-082508-K-en.json</span>
    </li>
    <li class="bc-product__spec">
        <span class="bc-product__spec-title">Unit of Measure:</span>
        <span class="bc-product__spec-value">item</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```